# Android FrameLayout use to load Fragment appears to live outside of parent LinearLayout

Tags: android, fragment, scrollview, android-framelayout

In android I have LinearLayout inside a ScrollView.
Nested in the LinearLayout are TextView, Other LinearLayouts etc..
I also have a FrameLayout used to load a Fragment

When the Fragment gets loaded it does not appears to live inside the LinearLayout inside the ScrollView.
Scrolling the screen has no affect on the position of the elements within the FrameLayout.

In the code below.  The line  is the FrameLayout that is loaded by a FragmentManager.  For some reason the button loaded in the FrameLayout Appears to be an overlay above the rest of the activity.  It does not moved when scrolled.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context="org.glucosio.android.fragment.OverviewFragment"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fab_size_normal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2px"
            android:background="#DADADA" />

        <TextView
            fontPath="fonts/lato-bold.ttf"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="@string/tab_tips"
            android:textColor="@color/glucosio_text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/random_tip_textview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="Always bring a banana to a party, Rose, bananas are good!"
            android:textColor="@color/glucosio_text" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">
             <Button
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="afdafsafsadsaf "/>
        </FrameLayout> 

        <!--  LOADED BY FRAGMENT MANAGER -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/chci_fragment_holder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>



// Here is the Fragment xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to post your xml code and fragment transaction

Comment: If I put a FrameLayout inside the LinearLayout and add a button inside of the FrameLayout, it works as it should.  The FrameLayout and Button seem to be a part of the outer LinearLayout and the position changes as I scroll.

But, if the Button is loaded as a Fragment, it appears to overlay the Activity (as if it's not a child of the LinearLayout).  It sits as the bottom of the screen regardless of scrolling

Comment: Is there a way to attach file?  The text is too large to paste and has greater than / less than signs.

Comment: I added the code in the answer section since it allowed me to paste the whole thing.  Near the bottom LOADED BY FRAGMENT MANAGER is where the FrameLayout appears to not live within the LinearLayout.  It instead seems to float over the rest of the layout

Comment: code is below.  Thanks in advance